# A way to not use Windows Authentication for ODBC query to SQL server

Tags: excel, authentication, odbc

All,

I have a workbook that contains an ODBC connection to an SQL Server and dumps the data from the query into a Table (VBA calls it a ListObject).  Right now, everything is using Windows Authentication.

Now I am trying to get other users to be able to use this workbook.  My DBA has decided it would be best to simply not use a windows account anymore, but instead to create a service account with password.

I have tried adjusting my workbook connection's authentication settings to use this service account (tried SSO and none with the actual authentication piece being in the connection string), but it still seems to be using windows authentication.  Is there a way to direct Excel to use a service account instead of the Windows credentials?

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried changing/adding the data source in the ODBC part of control panel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.  Apparently, if you have TrustedConnection=yes in your connectionstring, it will ignore the UID and try authentication with Windows :-)  Deleting that from my connection string seemed to work :-)